# Как перебрать все комбинации формулы?

Tags: c#

Необходмио перечислить все возможные формулы произвольного размера, используются цифры 0, 1, 2, переменная x иоперации -, +, *, а также скобки. 
Размер выражения - число использованных операций.
Например, формулы размера 1: 0+1, x*2, размера 4: x*x+2*x+1, (1+x)*1*2+0

Удалось сделать только "статически" и без скобок. Как это возможно реализовать в "движении" ??

https://repl.it/repls/AntiqueHoneydewCharactermapping  //код и тамже можно выполнить его

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class MainClass {
  public static bool onlyOneVariable(params char[] values) => values.Count(char.IsLetter) == 1;

  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var formulas = ( 
      from num1 in new[] { '0', '1', '2', 'X' }
      from num2 in new[] { '0', '1', '2', 'X' }

      from op1 in new[] { '-', '+', '*' }
      where onlyOneVariable(num1, num2)
      select $"{num1} {op1} {num2} "

    );
    foreach(var formula in formulas.Take(10)) {
      Console.WriteLine(formula);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: `Удалось сделать только "статически" и без скобок. Как это возможно реализовать в "движении"` что это значит?

Comment: то, что ваша программа выводит не решает же вашу задачу даже для 1 операции без скобок. У вас должно быть минимум 24 варианта, это если без повторений. И вот это `0 - X` и это `X - 0` вы считаете за один вариант или два? А это  `0 - X` и это `X + 0`? В общем, ваша задача не ясна.

Comment: "Необходмио" корректно и полно сформулировать задачу, а не вываливать сюда поток сознания. Только тогда, возможно, эту задачу удастся решить.

Comment: В текущей формулировке - решения не существует.

Comment: https://vk.cc/9Uan1r  вот такая вот задача (скриншотом условие заснял а то ломается при копипасте) =)

Comment: вы там AST проходите что ли, и вам надо генератор с парсером написать? Иначе я не знаю, как посчитать, что `1*x+2 то` же самое, что `x+2+0`

Comment: Сейчас даю ссылку на курс, вкратце: foreach,IEnumerable и yield return. Сам голову сломал что хотят, видимо никто задачу не осилил - комментов нет =)
https://ulearn.me/course/basicprogramming2/foreach_IEnumerable_i_IEnumerator_49c485c2-d2a7-4362-a473-5757719bd002

Comment: Скажем так, без условий про скобки и эквивалентности формул - задача будет элементарной, например, рекурсивным перебором. Скобки добавляют немного сложности, но эквивалентность формул сложность увеличивает так, что я не удивляюсь, что никто из новичков не решил. Я думаю, надо у препода спрашивать, что он имеет ввиду и как он предполагает вы будете это решать.

Comment: >спрашивать
"Решай, там легко" =)
Потому и затык случился

Comment: Значит надо переспросить. Я бы мог потратить часа три и наклепать решение, которое вы не поймете, но это будет пустой тратой времени. Идите к преподу и узнавайте, как он предполагает вы это решите.

Comment: оно решаемо, но тот способ, которым бы я решил, он далеко выйдет за рамки курса для начинающих. Потому либо я простую задачу для себя в голове свел к сложной, либо задача не соответствует курсу. Потому я вас и отправил к преподу.

Comment: Неадекватная сложность это, кажется, фирменная черта курса. Окей, если "закроем пальцем" все эти приколы со скобками и прочие ухищрения. Возможно ли как-то "прокачать" код который я прислал чтобы <   select $"{num1} {op1} {num2} "> был не "фиксированый" а скажем ввел я 2 и получил формулу Цифра Операнд Ц О Ц; ввел 3 и получил Ц О Ц О Ц О Ц

Comment: Накатал ответом

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим часть задачи, где надо только сегенерировать формулы, без проверки уникальности и скобочек.

Бинарная операция, которыми являются `+`, `-` и `*`, всегда содержат левую сторону, правую и операнд. Например, `x+1`, где `x` -левая, `1`- правая, `+` - операнд.

Предположим, что мы строим уравнение, и у нас уже есть левая сторона и операнд, например `x+`, тогда осталось добавить к нему правую сторону, которая может либо закончить выражение, например `x+1`, либо оставить его незаконченным, чтобы можно было операцию по добавлению правой сторны повторить `x+1+`.

Отсюда появляется рекурсивная функция. Я добавли только отслеживание уже использованных операций и операнодов, чтобы они в формулах не дублировались

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFormulas(string[] operands, string[] operators,
            bool[] operandsUsed, bool[] operatorsUsed,
            int operCount, List<string> states)
{
    if (operCount == 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<operands.Length; i++)
        {
            if (operandsUsed[i]) continue;
            var oper = operands[i];
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var state in states) sb.Append(state);
            sb.Append(oper);
            yield return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {       
        for (int j=0; j<operators.Length; j++)
        {
            if (operatorsUsed[j]) continue;
            var op = operators[j];

            for (int i=0; i<operands.Length; i++)
            {
                if (operandsUsed[i]) continue;
                var oper = operands[i];

                operandsUsed[i] = true;
                operatorsUsed[j] = true;

                states.Add(oper);
                states.Add(op);
                foreach(var f in GetFormulas(operands, operators,operandsUsed, operatorsUsed, operCount-1, states))
                    yield return f;

                operandsUsed[i] = false;
                operatorsUsed[j] = false;

                states.RemoveAt(states.Count-1);
                states.RemoveAt(states.Count-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как использовать:

```
var operands = new[] { "0", "1", "2", "X" };
var operators = new[] { "+", "-", "*" };
var L = 1;

foreach (var f in GetFormulas(operands,operators, 
            new bool[operands.Length], new bool[operators.Length],
            L, new List<string>()))
    Console.WriteLine(f);
```

Где `L` - может принимать значение от 0 до 3, так как у нас только максимум 3 не повторяющихся оператора.

Пример вывода:

```
0+1
0+2
0+X
1+0
1+2
1+X
2+0
2+1
2+X
X+0
X+1
X+2
0-1
0-2
0-X
1-0
1-2
1-X
2-0
2-1
2-X
X-0
X-1
X-2
0*1
0*2
0*X
1*0
1*2
1*X
2*0
2*1
2*X
X*0
X*1
X*2
```